# Kohana 3 JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kohana, kohana-3

We have a simple JQuery date picker that we are trying to include on a page.  The function works on a strait html site, however, when we include the working function via Kohana the function does not work.  We have tried including it both as a file by loading all of the JavaScript references in an array in a template and printing them with

```
<?php foreach($scripts as $file) { echo HTML::script($file, NULL, TRUE), "\n"; }?>
```

As well as simply putting the script in a separate view and using view::factory to include the file.  When we do the latter the `</script>` tag is not recognized by browsers or at least its syntax highlighting is not picking it up, though this does not effect other scripts such as Google maps.  For what ever it is worth, here is the function:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".datepick").datepicker();
});
```

and the element it is acting on is:

```
<input class="datepick" id="to" type="text" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for us.  We are getting pretty desperate to make this one little simple function work.

Comment: There's a typo in what you posted - your code references the class "datepicker", but that `<input>` element just says "datepick".  Is that just a transcription problem?

Comment: Ah, indeed, it does not fix the issue however, it was just a typo from when I wrote up this post.

Comment: OK well it's good to get that straight before you get 5 answers telling you about it :-)

Comment: Hey david, have you tried comparing the markup from the straight html and the kohana print out? Also might be worth checking the resources are loaded properly using something like firebug.

Comment: Indeed, we did all of the above Rob.  The problem was actually an oversight in how the JQuery libraries were being added.  Unbeknown to us Kohana prints them in reverse order... and the JQuery UI library was being added before the JQuery core.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the last `TRUE` on the `HTML::script()` call, as that will add `index.php` to your script URL, implying that you are using PHP to serve the actual script files.

In this case, I think your call should just be:

```
<?php foreach ($scripts as $file) { echo HTML::script($file), "\n"; } ?>
```

Comment: Should we set it to false in that case or just leave it off?

Comment: its FALSE by default, so you choose.

Comment: Thanks man, page load times actually shot down a bit after this... which is kind of strange since it was not actually parsing and compiling any php, but we will take it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to Kohana but to your HTML code.

How do you include your scripts (is jQuery included before your javascript code) ?